# java ajax autocomplete not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

Ajax auto complete is not working. I debug the code and found that in my controller where I wrote the json line the debugger failed to debug there. I am new too this, plz help me out.

Controller

```
    response.setContentType("application/json");
        try {
                String term = request.getParameter("term");
                System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);

                AutoData a = new AutoData();
                a.setName(term);

                DataDao d = new DataDao();
                List<AutoData> data = d.getData();


                String searchList = new Gson().toJson(data);
                response.getWriter().write(searchList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

DataDAO

```
public class DataDao {
        private String sql;
        private ResultSet rs;


        public List<AutoData> getData(){
            List<AutoData> aData = new ArrayList<AutoData>();
            try{
            sql = "select * from userdetails";
            rs = DBConnection.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){

                AutoData a = new AutoData();
                a.setName(rs.getString("userid"));
                aData.add(a);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return aData;





}
}
```

AJAX CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
                $("#search").autocomplete({     
                source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url : "AutoController",
                        type : "GET",
                        data : {
                                term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) {
                                response(data);
                        }
                });
        }
});
});
});
```

Comment: function named *function* has no variable parameters defined . should'nt it be *function(var a)* ?

Comment: @Srinath - Not working when the controller return the result.

Comment: well i dont work much on javascript ... which part of code do you feel is bugged ? i dont see the *controller* returning any thing

Comment: @Srinath - there is some issue in this code, debug stops on this line.
                String searchList = new Gson().toJson(data);  and controller is returning a search list written after the above code.

Comment: Try printing *searchList* data elements to see whats contained in it .... Without some kind of stacktrace of data value its hard to find an issue ... Last line is to print to the httpResponse and not return

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have not added the gson api in the correct folder. So better make sure while adding the APIs.

Comment: No API means it wont compile then